# Comparing a string DateTime param in an Ecto query inside a Phoenix controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Not finding out how to compare a user-posted DateTime string to an Ecto 'updated_at' column in a Postgresql database from inside a Phoenix controller. Here is the code (the user-posted DateTime string conforms to a NaiveDateTime format)...

```
defmodule Myapp.FooController do
  use MyappWeb, :controller
  alias Myapp.Repo
  alias Myapp.Foo
  import Ecto.Query


  def updates(conn, params) do

      query = from a in Foo, where: a.updated_at > ^params["date"]

      updates = Repo.all(query)

      json conn, updates

    end
  end
```

I am not finding any good solution to this problem. There are two SO examples using Timex but I have not been able to get that solution to work. Any help is much appreciated! I am finding it hard to believe that in the books I have purchased and other documentation there is not any example of what must be a common use case. Thank you!

This code is in Phoenix 1.5.8, Elixir 1.11.4, Erlang 23 erts 11.2. All the rest of the app is working good it is only this DateTime comparison which is causing the problem.

The deps are...

```
defp deps do
  [
  {:phoenix, "~> 1.5.8"},
  {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 4.1"},
  {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.4"},
  {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
  {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.11"},
  {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2", only: :dev},
  {:phoenix_live_dashboard, "~> 0.4"},
  {:telemetry_metrics, "~> 0.4"},
  {:telemetry_poller, "~> 0.4"},
  {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
  {:jason, "~> 1.0"},
  {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"}
  ]
end
```

Comment: Hi! I think the problem here is not with Ecto and the query part, but with the way you are accessing params. `'date'` (with single quotes) is a charlist, and you probably want to use a string, `"date"`. If that doesn't work, can you try `IO.inspect(params)` and paste what is printed?

Comment: Also, can you provide us with an example of the date parameter being supplied to the controller?  You may need to convert it to a `%DateTime{}` struct before attempting the comparison.

Comment: @sabiwara - Yes, the original code does have double quotes around the param. I made a mistake entering it here. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @MiquelFuentes can you please inspect `params` and share the result? Also, the SQL query that you can find in the logs or any error that you get would help. Otherwise it is not possible to reproduce or debug the issue ;)

Comment: (I tried `params = %{"date" => "2020-10-25 07:27:04"}` and it worked just fine)

Comment: `{:ok, datetime} = NaiveDateTime.new(params["date"], ~T[00:00:00])`, convert to NaiveDateTime seems good?